# angular 5: ngx-bootstrap timepicker locale

Tags: angular, timepicker, ngx-bootstrap

I am using timepicker from ngx-bootstrap like this :

```
 <timepicker [(ngModel)]="startDateTime" name="startTimes" #startTime="ngModel" required [showMeridian]="true"></timepicker>
```

Trying to have locale working for `'de'` (Deutsche) and `'ja'` (Japaneese) based on the logged in user like this:

app.module.ts:

```
import {TimepickerModule, BsLocaleService} from 'ngx-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        TimepickerModule.forRoot() 
    ],
    declarations: [

    ],
    providers: [
        BsLocaleService 
    ]
})
```

my.component.ts:

```
import {Component, OnInit, Inject, ViewChild, SimpleChange, SimpleChanges} from '@angular/core';
import {TimepickerModule, BsLocaleService} from 'ngx-bootstrap';
import {listLocales} from 'ngx-bootstrap';
import {deLocale} from 'ngx-bootstrap';
import {jaLocale} from 'ngx-bootstrap';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    templateUrl: './my-component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./my-component.less']
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    locale = 'ja'; //hardcoded for testing
    locales = listLocales();
    startDateTime = new Date();

    constructor(private _localeService: BsLocaleService) {
        this._localeService.use(this.locale);
    }
```

This isn't working for locale, the functionality of `timepicker` is working fine though. I am pretty new to this and the documentation on the site doesn't have anything about the `timepicker` locale. I have implemented this by looking at the `datepicker` locale : https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker#locales

What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add this piece in the module

```
// imports

import { defineLocale, jaLocale } from 'ngx-bootstrap';

defineLocale('ja', jaLocale);

// @NgModule(...)
```

Comment: Can this be in a feature module or should it be in app.module?